# A set is a manifold iff a subset of it is a manifold.(p.28 Guillemin & Pollack)

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology

Does this statement in the picture tells me that "A set is a manifold iff a subset of it is a manifold.(p.28GP)" :

> [image]

Could anyone explain this for me please?

Comment: Euclidean open balls are manifolds. A manifold is basically a space which looks *locally* like a ball (every point has such neighborhood). So, a space is manifold iff it is locally a manifold.

Comment: So my interpretation was wrong?@Berci

Comment: I would say that that interpretation is wrong. To me, the laconic way to summarize that statement is "A space is a manifold iff it admits an open cover by manifolds" (together with knowledge of what the subspace topology is).

Comment: You missed a quantifier. A set is a manifold if and only if *every* subset of a certain kind is a manifold, namely, a certain neighborhood of every point.